# Using jquery toggle to change button icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery toggle command like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/hbz9oa34/

```
$(".searchbtn").click(function () {
    $("#search").toggle();
});
```

What is the best way for me to change the search icon into a close icon after the toggle has opened the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CSS` instead of `img` tag to make it more generic.

CSS:

```
.icon-search {
  background: url("/img/search.svg");
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;

}

 // update the width and height as required.

.icon-close {
  background: url("/img/close.svg");
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".searchbtn").click(function () {
     $(this).find("i").toggleClass("icon-search icon-close")
});
```

HTML:

```
  <a href="#" class="searchbtn"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this i made a few modifications on your html css and jquery [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/hbz9oa34/1/)

```js
$('a').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('close')
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.input {
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.header {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.nav {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
#search {
    display: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.searchbtn{
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.menu-open{
    background:url('https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSaDYCb1sQ4jBwqwAhvjuupepjUw2PTrzJAnFXxA7Q3VsrCHit_Af75fR0');
     background-size:100% 100%;
}

.close{
    background:url('http://www.wpclipart.com/computer/icons/close_button_red.png');
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="header">
<a href="index.html"><img src="./img/logo.svg"></a>

<a  class="searchbtn menu-open" ></a>

        <form id="search">
            <input type="text" class="input" id="keyword" placeholder="Keyword">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/hbz9oa34/3/

You can add a wrapper for your search button and search form:

```
<div class="header__search">
  ...
</div>
```

Then, on click on search button you can add class to that wrapper to indicate that search is opened:

```
$('.header__search').addClass('header__search--opened');
```

Now you can change the icon with css.

Then, on click on close button you can remove previously added class:

```
$('.header__search').removeClass('header__search--opened');
```